# Two different forms on one $(document).ready(function) submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jqueryform

I have two different forms which basically do the same thing so just for an ease of use and less coding is there any way I can assign both of them on one `$(document).ready(function())`.

My original `$(document).ready` looks like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#transaction_form_new").on('submit', (function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var formData = new FormData(this);
      formData.append('farm', {{farm.id}});
      $.ajax({ ... })
```

This one is for creating a new form and i want to add the 'edit_form' also.
I tried it like this but with no result:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#transaction_form_new"),$("#transaction_form_edit").on('submit', (function(e) {
```

Comment: `$("#transaction_form_new"),$("#transaction_form_edit")` uses the esoteric "comma operator" - and as such `$("#transaction_form_new")` does nothing.  You *probably* wanted:  `$("#transaction_form_new, #transaction_form_edit").on`  (both selectors inside a single string, using the comma *selector*

Comment: See: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @freedomn-m suggested, the correct way to do that is:

`$("#transaction_form_new, #transaction_form_edit").on`
Both selectors inside a single string, using the comma selector